# Possible / how to perform bytecode modification to the "return" statement in a Java method using Javassist?

Tags: java, bytecode, instrumentation, agent, javaagents

I'm trying to use Javassist to bytecode modify the following code such that I can capture the result before it is returned.

I know I can use [setBody](https://www.javassist.org/html/javassist/CtBehavior.html#setBody(java.lang.String)) in CtBehavior to overwrite the complete method body but I think it's overkill...

I have tried two options but both options give me the error:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal exception table end_pc 793 in method 'String com.abc.myplayground.test.echo(java.lang.String)'
```

Option 1 - remove Line a2 using this [technique](https://coderedirect.com/questions/386086/modifying-line-numbers-in-javassist) and then add Line b2 and b3 to the method.

Option 2 - add Line b2 and b3 **ABOVE** Line a2, i.e. Line a2 never runs as Line b3 will do the `return`.

I wonder if Javassist allows modifying the `return` statement in some ways, or such operation is not allowed and I have to use the `setBody` approach.

Original code:

```java
public String echo(String dummyText) throws RuntimeException { // Line a1
    return dummyText.toUpperCase(); // Line a2
} // Line a3
```

Target code after bytecode modification:

```java
public String echo(String dummyText) throws RuntimeException { // Line b1
    String result = dummyText.toUpperCase(); // Line b2
    return result; // Line b3
}
```

Comment: Please explain **what** you actually want to achieve and not **how** you think it should be done. The transformation you are describing here does not add any value. After capturing the result, you surely want to do something with it, e.g. log it, modify it, write it to a database or whatever. You seem to be struggling with Javassist. So just in my answer to your previous question, I am suggesting you to use AspectJ instead. Your use cases consistently seem to be perfect fits for it. Of course, you can also solve the problem with Javassist. But first help us understand your actual goal.

Comment: Generally, trying to transform *bytecode* while still thinking in terms of *source code* lines doesn’t work, except for a few trivial cases. It’s the fundamental problem of the Javassist library to invite developers to this approach, leading to some quick success, followed by stall for nontrivial problems. As long as your problem still is “replace everything with this statement”, it’s on the trivial side and `setBody` will do. I don’t know why you think it’s “overkill”; as long as your problem stays as described, your second approach is overkill.